# DevExpress XtraReport: filterString editor disabled

Tags: c#, wpf, filter, devexpress, xtrareport

I have done a report, using also the filterString editror.

Now I'm doing the second, putting it in the same namespace of previous. But now the filterString editor is disabled, both for second and first report.

Why? Does it exist an option o something similar to enable it?

EDIT: here a screenshot[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it was because I take data from an obervableCollection, so I've put "DataSource" to none, instead of database. This is the cause.

Put it to database again, and the filter string editor is enabled. Weird.. but so it is!

Comment: Totally saved my life :) 
Thank you!